# Как убрать отступы по бокам контента внутри Android-WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview, width

В `WebView`  вношу данные и ожидаю что картинка как и текст будут занимать всю ширину экрана. Но по бокам, что у текста, что у картинки остается свободное пространство приблизительно `8dp`.

В классе активити:

```
// Set content
String content = bodyContent; //сюда передаю тело документа с разметкой.

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int displayWidth = display.getWidth();

View webLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.partial_article_web, null);
web = webLayout.findViewById(R.id.content);

WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();
settings.setTextZoom(storage.getTextZoom());
settings.setSupportZoom(false);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

web.addJavascriptInterface(this, "android");

web.loadDataWithBaseURL("", asHtmlPage(content, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

А вот так формирую данные для загрузки во `WebView`:

```
private String asHtmlPage(String body) {

    String style = "<style>" +
            "body { font-family: 'sans-serif-light', sans-serif; }" +
            "img { display: inline; height: auto; max-width: 100%; } " +
            "</style>";
    String meta = "<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>";

    return "<html><head>" + style + meta + "</head><body>" + body + "</body></html>";
}
```

Разметка `WebView`:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/content"
    style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

Пробовал:

1. комментировать

   ```
   settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
   settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
   ```
2. передвигал блок  `meta` с `<head>`  в `<body>`
3. Изменял: `<meta name='viewport' content='width=" +  displayWidth + " , initial-scale=1'>";`
4. В стиле менял `max-width: 100%;` на `max-width: " + displayWidth + ";`

Сам контент который загружаю не имеет никаких отступов и границ по бокам.

Помогите разобраться, откуда берется этот неожиданный Padding.

UPD: 
По замечанию @Timur Mukhortov, исправил `@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin` в `xml` разметке `WebView` на `16dp`.

Comment: @Timur Mukhortov спасибо за подсказку. Исправил.

Comment: так, дименшены лучше, если у вас они везде заданы как стандарт. Ну тип можете создать отдельный ресурс с отступом для WebView и везде его использовать.

Comment: Я их поменял да более явные цифры только в вопросе. А так, стараюсь использовать ссылки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашу переменную `content`, добавьте следующий контейнер:

```
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
```

> По умолчанию webview имеет некоторый отступ / отступ в теле. Если вы
>   хотите удалить этот отступ / поле, переопределите тег body..

Comment: Извините, ввел в заблуждение "@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"  - это 16dp. Но в данном случае это только ссылка на ресурс. И она применена к верхнему и нижнему полю. А боковые у меня убраны.

Comment: попробуйте сейчас

Comment: Это сработало! Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Рад что вам помогло)